# Solaris 5.10 - Can't wait on C++ named semaphores

Tags: c++, solaris, semaphore, fork

I'm trying to use C++ POSIX named semaphores (i.e. sem_open(), sem_wait(), sem_post()) on a Solaris 5.10 machine. The goal is to create a banking server program, which can accept many client connections simultaneously, and carry out requested transactions. I accept each request, and then fork off a child process to maintain that connection. The point of the assignment is to synchronize these processes with semaphores and shared memory. My program is structured as follows:

```
#define BALANCE_SEM "/balance_sem"

// listen on a port and other stuff

static int64_t *balance = (int64_t *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(*balance), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

sem_t *balance_lock;
if ((balance_lock = sem_open(BALANCE_SEM, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: unable to initialize semaphore: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

while (1) {
    // accept request from client

    int pid = fork();

    // child process
    if (pid == 0) {

        sem_t *balance_sem;
        if ((balance_sem = sem_open(BALANCE_SEM, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: unable to open existing named semaphore: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        transaction t = getTransactionFromClient();
        switch (t.type) {
            case 0:
                if (sem_wait(balance_sem) < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to wait on semaphore: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                }

                *balance = *balance + t.amount;
                sem_post(balance_sem);
            case 1:
                if (sem_wait(balance_sem) < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to wait on semaphore: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                }

                *balance = *balance - t.amount;
                sem_post(balance_sem);
        }

    // parent process
    } else {
        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is that everything works when I run the server program on Linux machines (I've tried several). However, when I run the server program on the Solaris machine, my error message is printed on the sem_wait() calls (but not on the sem_open()) calls, with strerror(errno) returning "Invalid argument". What could be wrong?

EDIT:

In fact, the same error occurs with the following Extremely simplified code, no forking required at all:

```
sem_t *balance_lock;
if ((balance_lock = sem_open(BALANCE_SEM, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, unable to initialize semaphore: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

if (sem_wait(balance_lock) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, failed to wait on semaphore: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: Were you planning on telling us which error happens on wait?

Comment: The failed `sem_wait()` call should leave `errno` set to a code indicating the nature of the problem.  It would be useful to see what that nature is.  How about calling `perror()` in your failure cases to output that information?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that, but I edited it in.

Comment: You've tagged the question correctly if you're compiling as C++, but speaking idiomatically there's really very little C++ here. In fact, aside from the missing `struct` prefix on `t`'s definition, I can't see _any_! Why is that?

Comment: Well, this is just a part of the program. I've got some classes and some inheritance going on in there to encapsulate some of the socket code, among other things. This is really just a stripped down version of the main function for the server program, so you don't see too much. Honestly, I could have probably written the entire thing in C anyway.

Comment: What could be wrong: (1) your semaphore could be closed before you get to `sem_wait()`, though nothing in the code you posted appears to do that.  Note that closing a semaphore is global to the whole system.  (2) something could be corrupting `*balance_sem`.  (3) Your implementation of POSIX semaphores could be buggy.

Comment: If the `sem_open()` succeeds but an immediately-following `sem_wait()` in the same process fails with `EINVAL`, as in the simplified example, then your semaphore implementation is broken.  I'm inclined to suspect that the failure *should* have been reported by `sem_open()`, and failure of that function to do so by returning `SEM_FAILED` could be the whole bug.  You could try checking whether `sem_open()` sets `errno` -- there's a chance it would do so on error but fail to returning the correct value.

Comment: Currently, the errno value set after sem_open() is EEXIST (File exists). If I change the value of BALANCE_SEM to "/balance_semiii", the errno value after sem_open() is ENOENT (No such file or directory). Does this yield any clues?

Comment: After re-reading the documentation, I guess this scenario seems impossible... If I can't use sem_open() to create named semaphores, do you think I should try System V semaphores, or creating POSIX semaphores in shared memory somehow?

Comment: I like POSIX semaphores better than System V semaphores, but at this point I have no confidence in your POSIX semaphore implementation.  System V semaphores are more broadly supported, and Solaris anyway has a System V heritage, so personally, I'd try the System V route.